# Sending a variable as data parameter in requests.post() in Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I'm trying to pass a variable to the data field in requests.post() and I continue to get the error,

```
  Error Response: {'error': {'message': 'Exception while reading request', 
'detail': 'Cannod decode: java.io.StringReader@1659711'}, 'status': 'failure'}
```

Here is my code

```
#Fill array from CSV
temp=[]
for row in csv.iterrows():
    index, data = row
    temp.append(data.tolist())


#Create new asset for all assets in CSV
for index, row in enumerate(temp):
    make = temp[index][0]
    serial = str(temp[index][1])
    date = str(temp[index][2])
    response = requests.post(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers, 
    data='{"asset_tag":"test1", "assigned_to":"test2", 
    "company":"test3", "serial_number":serial}')
```

I originally tried feeding it directly from the CSV using

```
str(temp[index][1])
```

This did not work, so I tried assigning `str(temp[index][1])` to the variable `serial` and then passing the variable like that but that also results in the same error.

A point in the right direction would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of sending the request payload body in string, pass it in json form.
requests.post accepts string in data variable and json in json variable. I faced a same issue while trying to make my first REST call to ServiceNow instance via Python. Hope this helps.

```
response = requests.post(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers, 
    json={"asset_tag":"test1", "assigned_to":"test2", 
    "company":"test3", "serial_number":serial})
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the single quotes from the following :

```
data='{"asset_tag":"test1", "assigned_to":"test2", 
       "company":"test3", "serial_number":serial}'
```

Use

```
data = {"asset_tag":"test1", "assigned_to":"test2", 
        "company":"test3", "serial_number":serial}
```

Answer (score 1):

rather than passing data=data, take data as dict and pass it as json=data.